# Using a class to store gamedata, best practise?

Tags: c#, class, instance

Im using Visual C# 2010 express. Im working on a game, and have come accross a small, newbie problem. Thing is, i guess we're dealing with a best practise type situation, and none of the few beginner books i have really helped with it, so i hope you guys can.

So, i have two forms, one is a splashscreen/startup form and the other is the main game window. I made a class that contains all world data, and when in the first screen user clicks on "new game", a new instance of this class is generated and populated with data.

So far so good.

The newgame button, in addition to creating the world instance, opens up the main game window.  The problem is, in the main game window, when i try to use attributes of the gameworld instance, it says that it doesnt exist in this context.

So, if i get it right, the created instance only exists within the first form class... is that correct?

So if i'd like to move that whole data, should i actually serialize and save the world class instance data, and load it in the second form? Or how should i approach this.

I understand it's a very newbie question, and i could propably hack it to work, but the thing is - i really feel like i have to understand everything im doing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a reference of the world data object in the splash screen, you can assign this to a public member in the main screen, or pass it to the main screen through a constructor.

so in the splash screen

```
FrmMain frmMain = new FrmMain();
frmMain.WorldData = this.WorldData;
```

if it is an instance member of the splash screen

or maybe something like

```
FrmMain frmMain = new FrmMain();
frmMain.WorldData = new WorldData();
```

or even

```
FrmMain frmMain = new FrmMain(this.WorldData);
```

or

```
FrmMain frmMain = new FrmMain(new WorldData());
```

with the FrmMain constructor as

```
public FrmMain(WorldData worldData)
{
    this.m_WorldData = worldData;
}
```

Have a look at [Passing Data Between Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)

Comment: Thank you, i get it now. I have to pass the object between forms for the form to be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a constructor on your game form that accepts an instance of your world class and assign it to a field of the same type - the field will be accessible to the game form methods.

```
World world;

// constructor
public GameForm (World world)
{
  this.world = world;
}

// Can now use `world` in all `GameForm` methods
```

Instead of constructor injection (as I have shown in my example), you can use [property injection](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?19914-Difference-between-constructor-injection-and-property-injection), though I like the former better (tends to ensure proper initialization - though you may want to check for a `null` being passed in).

Comment: Thank you also for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using just windows forms, and not XNA or similar framework, where theres no winforms.

Startup form:

```
void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GameWorld gw = new GameWorld();
    // Initialize gw instance here

    GameForm mainForm = new GameForm(gw);
    mainForm.Show();
}
```

And add a constructor to the game form:

```
public class GameForm
{
    private GameWorld _gw;
    public GameForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public GameForm(GameWorld gw) : this()
    {
        _gw = gw;
    }
}
```

At that point you can use private variable _gw in the game form.

Also, i would suggest passing the GameWorld instance through the constructor, not the property as that value is crucial for the form. Generally properties might be better suited to provide a way to adjust some behavior, and any constructor parameter can be seen as mandatory for the object to work as it should.
You can also make default constructor (the one without parameters) private.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the data and if the world object class is serializable, You might think about caching it. Then each form that needs the data can just get it from the cache whenever it is needed.